# Как записать псевдоэлемент в style чтобы выглядело так: <p style="::placeholder{ padding:10px; }">?

Tags: html, css, псевдоэлемент

Правильно псевдоэлемент записывается так:
`<style> p::placeholder{ padding-left:10px; } </style>`

Но весь вопрос в том, что: "Как записать placeholder в строке со стайлом, в одной строке не выходя в стайл "внешний"?
Чтобы было что то вроде этого:

`<p style="p::placeholder{margin:10px;}"></p>`

Вроде бы гдето видел подобное только совсем не так. Но вдруг есть какое нибудь решение не выходить во внешний стайл на псевдоэлемент.
Аналогично давно всех мучающий вопрос как записать псевдокласс :hover?

```
<a href="#" style=":hover{color:green;}">решение!</a>
```

Comment: Никак. Никак. Никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы делаете ИНЛАЙН-стили.
2. Инлайн-стили применяются к ЭЛЕМЕНТАМ - тем, в которых они прописаны.
3. Инлайн-стили НЕ ПРИМЕНЯЮТСЯ к классам. В инлайн-стилях перечисляются    свойства самого элемента, т.е., та часть CSS-кода, которая ВНУТРИ фигурных скобок CSS-селектора. В данном случае CSS-селектором является сам элемент.
4. Псевдоклассы с точки зрения CSS - то же самое, что и классы.
5. Псевдоэлементы - не то же самое, что содержащие их элементы.

А вы пытаетесь в инлайн-стиль для элемента пропихнуть свойства псевдокласса (что неверно в корне) или псевдоэлемента (т.е, НЕ ТОГО элемента, в котором инлайн-стиль).

Поэтому без выноса во внешний тег `<style>` или файл `.css`  - никак.